# How to send spring boot actuator endpoint information to graphite?

Tags: graphite, codahale-metrics, spring-boot-actuator

I'm going to make application monitoring system. I'm using spring-boot actuator and I can make some information like metrics, health and etc. See a attatchment.

As you can see, there are so many things such as memory, heap to counter and gauges.(sample.actuator.SampleController.hello.* are made by com.codahale.metrics.annotation.Timed)

And I want to send those information to graphite to monitor. Google said those code.

```
@Configuration
public class MonitoringConfig {
    @Autowired
    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    @Bean
    public GraphiteReporter graphiteReporter() {
        Graphite graphite = new Graphite(new InetSocketAddress("70.50.8.111",
                2003));

        GraphiteReporter reporter = GraphiteReporter
                .forRegistry(metricRegistry).prefixedWith("boot")
                .build(graphite);

        reporter.start(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return reporter;
    }
}
```

but reporter send only counter and gauge. For inserting other information to reporter, what should I do?

Please help....